# Removing the listener to avoid memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am having a question about memory leak when listeners are set for a custom view.
I have a custom view MyView as below:

```
class MyView extends View{
    private IOnSelectionListener listener;

    public void setOnSelectionListener(IOnSelectionListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void removeOnSelectionListener(){
        this.listener = null;
    }
}
```

I have an  Activity which implements the  IOnSelectionListener. The activity have the code as below

```
MyView myView;
public onCreate(){
    myView = (MyView)findViewbyId(R.id.selectionview);
    myView.setOnSelectionListener(this);

}

onDestroy(){
    myView.removeOnSelectionListener()
}
```

Now when I, navigate to another activity or I change the orientation, should the listener should be removed for the MyView  to avoid the memory leak?

Also if WeakReference is used, then do we need to have a removeListener method?

Regards,
SrS

Answer (score 1):

I am not a pro, but from the 1st time i create a simple app until i created the quite complex one, i **never** remove any of my listener just for freeing memory.

I think the OS can handle it pretty well